# Business intelligence wont display data cube, problem with connectivity

Tags: c#, data-mining, business-intelligence

I am using VS 2008 version 3.5 SP1 and MySQL server 2008 R2
When using business intelligence and when I start adding dimensions and so the database is connected fine and BI is retrieving the info, but when I make the data cube and click on process this happens http://img64.imageshack.us/img64/1597/errorhb.png

I did everything, I made sure that the browser service was enabled and I made sure of the server name ..etc but still no luck ...

Answer (score 1):

Your screen shot suggests you're trying to connect to an instance of SQL Express. You can't build cubes on that version of SQL Server, you need Standard or above.